# Python GTK3 exec bash command and show output line by line

Tags: python, terminal, gtk3

Im new to Python and Gtk, im trying to make a small app that will execute a Bash command and show output "real time", line by line, just like when installing some app via synaptic it shows in terminal-like widget details of install process.

Do I use Vte.Terminal for this or subprocess.Popen? and how do i display output?
I was looking at Gtk.TextView() but im not sure how to use it.

```
p = subprocess.Popen('locate zend', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print line,  
retval = p.wait()
```

In the nutshell I would like to execute shell command and show the exact output as it would show in regular terminal (rows, colors, bold text....). Somehow Vte.Terminal makes sense to me, cause TextView will show regular text.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use a TextView. Here are some links explaining how:

[PyGTK FAQ: How do I send the output of an external process to a gtk.TextView without freezing the GUI?](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq14.023.htp)
[Blog post: Redirecting the stdout on a gtk.TextView](https://pygabriel.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/redirecting-the-stdout-on-a-gtk-textview/)